# When I perform a who-is lookup on a .me domain name, why is it not able to find it despite the fact that it works?

Tags: domains, web-hosting

I know some people who are hosting a TeamTalk server on their Linux VPS. They are using a .me domain. I wanted to see who their domain registrar was, as well as their nameservers, but I wasn't able to find anything for the .me domain.
I guess my queston is, can you make your own top-level domain and be your own domain registrar? If so, how does this process work? Do you need some sort of DNS software installed on your server?

Comment: Use registry whois server: https://domain.me/ for the web interface. As for your other questions: no, anyone can not create any top-level for obvious reasons of coordination; you will need to go through ICANN when the process is opened again ; and then you will become a registry, not a registrar.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick google search for *.me whois lookup* (wink) and one of the results it returned was http://whois.instra.com/me.  Not all whois sites will lookup all TLDs

Comment: No need to do that. Go to the authoritative sources, the IANA webpage on .ME will list its registry and the whois server to use: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/me.html   . Never use anything else than the registry whois server.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, you are right, but it was more a statement on how easy it is to find your own answer ;o)

Comment: But both using a search engine (and a specific one on top of that) and going to a registrar whois website (inside of the registry one) are not good advises, hence my comment.